# Table view not inserting row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I went through the sample code from the apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913

The problem is that, with that recent xcode version, the table view does not insert new row before updating. And the app crashed.

I add recipes if find, then I click on edit, the Add Ingredient button show up, so I click to Add Ingredient... Putting the name of ingredient and the amount in the label, the click on the Save button.
Now the ingredient does not inserting the row I just added. and When I click on Done, the app crashed.

Crashed log:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 1 from section 1 which only contains 1 rows before the update'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone SE (2nd generation) (BE65BFCF-47EE-441B-85E1-E5C6CF6A586B) - Runtime: iOS 14.4 (18D46) - DeviceType: iPhone SE (2nd generation)

Could somebody fix this?

Thank a lot.

Comment: Need some debugging information here. What is the error shown in Xcode console?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question to provide the details of the crash and show the relevant code.

Comment: And could you please add steps to reproduce this error?